# Can I exclude directories from GitHub Dependabot?

Tags: github, npm, automation, monorepo, dependabot

I have a directory `/experiments` in my repo which contains - surprise! - experiments. Those usually come with their own `package.json` which includes dependencies that were up to date at the time I made the experiment but might be outdated by now. I have no intent to keep them up to date as the experiments are just proofs of concepts - concepts I might want to use later in the project but I would then implement anew in the main project.

Unfortunately Dependapot sends me a lot of PRs that are about those dependencies in `/experiments`. Many of them require manual efforts on my end. So I would like to tell Dependabot to not send any notifications or create PRs for everything that is in the `/experiments` directory (but keep creating PRs for dependencies in the main project).

I didn't really find much docs about how to configure Dependabot on GitHub, but I came up with this:

`/.github/dependabot.yml`:

```sh
version: 2
updates:

  # Ignore experiments:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/experiments"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "*"
```

It doesn't seem to work though. Today I received another PR from Dependabot that bumped one of the dependencies in `/experiments`. It was automatically merged, so no effort on my end, but still a bit annoying.

How can I do this right?

Comment: We have the exact same problem with our proof of concepts and Dependabot. I didn't find any solution for this either.

Comment: Just found the solution, see my answer below.

Comment: where's your answer @Dominik (:

Comment: I remember that there was an answer but it was wrong. Maybe they deleted it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible as of May 2023: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/4364

Comment: Thanks for the info! That's a bummer :-| But now at least we know where to lobby for this feature XD

Comment: For anyone looking to have this feature implemented: there's a feature request to add monorepo support to dependapot and it's gaining tractions. Maybe, if you vote for it and post your use case, it might get higher priority. See: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/4364#issuecomment-1782984411